# Was Bluetooth AMP actually used?

Tags: wireless, standardisation

Bluetooth AMP (Alternative MAC/PHY) is a way for bluetooth of using the 802.11 MAC/PHY, e.g. Wi-Fi, as a transport to send "High Speed" data, hence the "HS" in the "Bluetooth 3.0 + HS" version in which it was introduced.

Is bluetooth AMP actually used, in a "off-the-shelf" product, between its introduction in 2009, and 2023 ? My educated guess is "no", as the Bluetooth 5.3 version removes AMP from the standard, but, I'm wondering if someone actually used that.

Thanks !